# Django - How to delete an object from a button in a table

Tags: django, object, button

**Objective:**
I want to delete an object from a table using a button in Django, but it's not working as expected. I've provided relevant parts of my code below. Can someone please guide me on what to add to `urls.py` and `views.py` to make this work?

**Database Attributes:**

- `_id`: ObjectId
- `response`: string
- `contact_id`: string
- `status`: string

**views.py:**

```py
def delete(request, id):  
    try:
        excel_data = get_object_or_404(ExcelData, id=id)  
        excel_data.delete()  
        return redirect('web_services_app:tables')
    except ExcelData.DoesNotExist:
        # Handle the case where the object doesn't exist
        return HttpResponse("The object you're trying to delete doesn't exist.")

**urls.py:**
path('delete/<int:id>/', views.delete, name='delete'),

**HTML Table in tables.html:**

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="data-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="font-weight: bold; color: black;">Response</th>
                <th scope="col" style="font-weight: bold; color: black;">Contact ID</th>
                <th scope="col" style="font-weight: bold; color: black;">Status</th>
                <th scope="col" style="font-weight: bold; color: black;">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for data in excel_data %}
            <tr class="table-row">
                <td class="table-data">{{ data.response }}</td>
                <td class="table-data">{{ data.contact_id }}</td>
                <td class="table-data">{{ data.status }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/web_services_app/delete/{{ data.id }}">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

I appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you! ❤️
```

Comment: What do you with not working as expected?

Comment: Thank u for your answer , the delete button is not working

Comment: So what happens if you click, is there something in the console, do you see the request being made in the "Network" tab of the console.

Comment: if i click , i found this in the console :
Not Found: /web_services_app/delete/None/

Comment: Can you provide the model?

Comment: together with the view that renders the table.

Comment: Models.py : 
from django.db import models

class ExcelData(models.Model):
    response = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    contact_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'web_services'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.response

views.py :
def tables(request):
    excel_data = ExcelData.objects.all()
    serializer = excel_serializers(excel_data, many=True) 

    context = {
        'excel_data': serializer.data
    }

    return render(request, 'tables.html', context)

Comment: what should i write and sorry i'm begginer on stackoverflow

Comment: relax, no need to worry, it is just easier because it makes the code more readable in the question and also more "canned".

Comment: You can use [`DeleteView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a serializer, and it will likely only complicate manners, so we can work with:

```
def tables(request):
    excel_data = ExcelData.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'tables.html', {'excel_data': excel_data})
```

In the template we then can work with the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#url), and use `pk`, since this will use the primary key field, regardless what its name is:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'web_services_app:delete' data.pk %}">Delete</a>
```

and we do the same in the view:

```
def delete(request, id):  
    try:
        excel_data = ExcelData.objects.get(pk=id)  
        excel_data.delete()
        return redirect('web_services_app:tables')
    except ExcelData.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("The object you're trying to delete doesn't exist.")
```

Likley the `_id` is a UUID, hence the path converter should use [**`<uuid:…>`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#path-converters):

```
path('delete/<uuid:id>/', views.delete, name='delete'),
```

Comment: what about urls.py :
    path('delete/<int:id>/', views.delete, name='delete'), ??

Comment: he said as en error :
NoReverseMatch at /web_services_app/tables/
Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['web_services_app/delete/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

line :
 <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'web_services_app:delete' data.pk %}">Delete</a>

Comment: There is an `ExcelData` in your database with `id` is `NULL`/`None`? You did pull the items from the database, right?

Comment: i'm not using a model because i uploaded an excel file on my database mongodb then i'm using it , so i think i have not an attribute id that's why he said id is none , if i'm wrong , how can i fix this error ?

Comment: @AdamRossonero: well given there is no database, how do you expect to *remove* the item? If there is no `.id`/`.pk`/whatever as unique key. Exactly what is `ExcelData` then?

Comment: non there is a database but there is not a model , i just create a colletion on my database then i uploaded an excel file on it and i'm using it , there is not an attribute id i said , and for the pk i think _id which is created automatically on mongodb is the pk

Comment: given all that is true, then `.id` should raise an attribute error. The fact that it returns `None` instead means something is wrong with the `ExcelData` class.

Comment: this is my models.py :
class ExcelData(models.Model):
    response = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    contact_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'web_services'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.response

Comment: Add `_id = models.ObjectIdField()` to the model.

Comment: in a MongoDB database, the ID is usually managed automatically as an ObjectId. I don't need to specify the _id attribute in my Django model. If I need the ID, I can get it directly from the MongoDB database when reading or deleting the data. and i think i don't need to use the models.py cz i have imported an excel file on my database as i said ,i just create a colletion on my database then i imported an excel file on it and i'm using it

Comment: @AdamRossonero: the point is just that the model objects will use the `_id` as primary key. You used a Django model with (I hope) Djongo fields. The reason to add `_id = models.ObjectIdField()` is simply to ensure that the mapping is done correctly...

Comment: The fact that the data originates from an excel file is irrelevant. You talk to a database through a model, whether that database is a mongodb or relational database is irrelevant. The model is not per se a table or anything: it acts as a proxy between the application and the database.